# Open with Explorer in Microsoft Edge - SharePoint 2013 aka on premises

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013

As you all know; IE support is ending early next year and quite a few on-premise Intranets are integrating Microsoft Edge.
We were checking if it is possible to enable the "Open with explorer" ribbon option in Microsoft Edge.

A few resources have mentioned that it is an IE only option because of some ActiveX implementation there which modern browsers do not share.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/117208/101122

But from Microsoft's documentation; they have mentioned how it would be possible in an SPO Tenant with Microsoft Edge. They mention:

a) configuring 'ConfigureViewInFileExplorer' policy in Edge and

b) running this Powershell SPO cmd: `Set-SPOTenant -ViewInFileExplorerEnabled $True`

So, i'm a bit confused now. Is it possible for Edge in the on-premises scenario too

**EDIT:**

---

i put the question in 2 forums and its been answered here:

The answer says that on premises SharePoint does not support this ribbon option in Edge

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/298868/101122

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with trevor, SharePoint on-premise doesn't support enabling "Open with explorer" ribbon option in the Microsoft Edge.